# Check if 3 given vertices from undirected graph belong to a cycle in most efficient way

Tags: algorithm, graph

Is it possible to perform some sort of pre-processing that would allow to answer the question efficiently (fast)?

The graph is connected, undirected, has no self loops neither parallel edges (a cycle is formed by at least 3 nodes).

Note that this a yes/no query, meaning that I just need to know whether such a cycle exits, which one doesn't matter.

Edit: My progress so far (based on **Nursultan** hint) and where I'm blocking:

I'm separating the graph into sub-components through articulation points, and then doubling articulation points in each sub-component they originally separated. This came from the following observation: 3 given vertices may belong to a cycle **iff** they all belong to a component with no articulation points. I have not proved this but I couldn't think of a counter example.

Assuming the observation above is correct (which seems very likely), the problem now is the 3 given vertices in the query may all be articulation points, in which case all of them would belong to several components, which in the worst case could lead to a slow O(n) query time complexity.

Another observation that seem helpful to address the described worst case is: there's at most 1 sub-graph to which 2 given articulation points may both belong to at the same time (I can prove this if needed), the observation easily leads to a worst case pre-processing space and time of O(n^2) (n is number of vertices), versus constant time queries, however O(n^2) preprocessing time is too slow (O(n^2) space is also too greedy). Can preprocessing be improved? a trade off of say log(n) query time expense would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Let's partition your graph into several subgraphs, which has this property:

> Every vertice in each subgraph belongs to some cycle and using this
>   cycle you can travel to any vertice from this subgraph.

So you can check if three vertices belong to a cycle by checking if they belong to some subgraph. It can be done in O(log V)

So how can we partition such graph?

1. Partition your graph into subgraphs (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bridge-in-a-graph/)
2. Remove all edges considered as bridges
3. Now you have several components. Every vertice that belongs to the same component, insert into the same set.

**NOTE:** As @ALTN mentioned this is not a correct solution. So maybe you must also partition each subgraph in articulation points. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/

Comment: There's a problem with this solution, check the figure from your link with the 7-vertex graph, node 0, 1 and 3 are all in same sub-graph but they don't belong to a cycle (1 must always be visited twice to loop from 0 to 3).

Comment: As @ALTN mentioned this is not a correct solution. So you must also partition each subgraph in articulation points and doubling them. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/

Comment: actually by dividing through articulation points and doubling them, it means articulation points belong to 2 or more sub-graphs, which means each of the 3 vertices given in the query, can belong to multiple subgraphs, is it possible to determine if they belong to a common subgraph fast?

Comment: @ALTN even they can belong to several subgraphs, each subgraph has mentioned property.

Comment: Do you mean I have to loop through all sub-graphs and check if any of them mentions all 3 vertices?

Comment: @ALTN nope. When subgraph is created, you can store all vertices of this subgraph in Set. So finding any element in Set is O(log N). So checking if three elements in cycle is O(log N)

Comment: Yes but there are multiple sub-graphs to check from, how are you going to avoid looping through them? in other words how do you determine which sub-graph to check on?

Comment: @ALTN I very appreciate that you checked and correct all my mistakes that I did before. Yes you are right. We can not easily identify the subgraph to which all 3 vertices or not belong to. I came only to the solution, when you can check in O(N). Thanks, good job ALTN.

Answer (score 1):

Having `A` as the adjacency matrix of the graph. `A^l_{i,j}` gives you the number of paths from `i` to `j` of length `l`. So `A^l_{i,i}` are the number of cycles for node `i`.

Precompute all `A^l` for `l>=3`. Let `n_1, n_2, n_3` be the nodes. Assuming they are part of the same cycle then there exists a cycle from each of them of the same length. Hence check in the same `A^l` if `A^l_{n_i, n_i}` have at least one cycle. They can be in different cycles though. So for each `l` the before criteria satisfied, see if you can find such `d_i, 1 <= i <= 3` between `n_1 -> n_2 -> n_3 -> n_1` such that `sum(d_i) = l`. Since you already computed the set `{A^l}` doing that is rather easy.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, I actually already found a solution with O(n^2) time and space complexity for preprocessing, and constant query time all based on @Nursultan hint (see edit in original question). I'm now hoping for preprocessing improvement, a query time tradeoff of maybe O(log(n)) would be fine.